# GPIO Configuration Issue Zephyr RTOS+PlatformIO+STM32

Tags: stm32, platformio, zephyr-rtos

This is probably a dumb question but I need some help : I'm trying to simply blink an LED on my STM32L073 board. The LED is connected to the PB6 pin here's my code :

```
#include <zephyr.h>
#include <device.h>
#include <devicetree.h>
#include <drivers/gpio.h>

void main(void)
{
    const struct device *dev;
    dev = device_get_binding("GPIOB");
    gpio_pin_configure(dev,6,GPIO_OUTPUT);
    while(1){
        gpio_pin_set(dev,6,1);
        k_msleep(1000);
        gpio_pin_set(dev,6,0);
        k_msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I'm using platformio with Zephyr RTOS framework
In prj.conf I do have :
`CONFIG_GPIO=y`
In zephyr.dts, for gpiob the label is well GPIOB so I don't understand what is wrong here, so if anyone can help me it would be great :)

Comment: Does it compile without any errors?
Does the GPIOB label exist in your zephyr.dts (see build folder) file?

Comment: maybe you could try the blinky example from zephyr basic samples? And modify to "blink" your custom led?

Comment: Yes it compile without errors and GPIOB does exist in zephyr.dts
I also tried to modify the blinky example but it doesn't work either

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but did you flash after compile?

Comment: Ahah, good question, yep I compile and then flash !

Comment: Did you see that the default peripheral mapping for the UART is PB6/PB7? Maybe there is a conflict.

Comment: Yes, but with a simple Arduino Code I'm able to blink the led so I don't think it's an issue that PB6 is also for the Uart

Comment: You say you use platformio. I don't know it. What other default symbols than CONFIG_GPIO are enabled?

Comment: Only CONFIG_GPIO=y, nothing else

Comment: The LD2 (green) on your board is situated at PA5. The LED on PB6 you are speaking about, is it on some kind of arduino extension board?

Comment: Besides. This would be a part of the other symbols, which I guess should be enabled:
CONFIG_SOC_SERIES_STM32L0X=y
CONFIG_SOC_STM32L073XX=y
CONFIG_PINCTRL=y

Comment: Nope, I just add a led to PB6, it's a custom board with an stm32l073 on it

Comment: I tried to add what you give, it still doesn't work and CONFIG_PINCTRL=y return an error

Comment: How did you connect the LED to the output?

Comment: with a transistor, but it's working because with a digitalWrite(PB6,HIGH) in ArduinoIDE it's working perfectly

Comment: When you use Zephyr, is the default setting for the output push-pull?

Comment: where can I see that ?

Comment: Changing "GPIO_OUTPUT" to "GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP" doesn't change anything